# Issue in setting system variable ES_PATH_CONF for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, system-variable

I have cloned `elasticsearch` project from GitHub to my local machine. Built it successfully and imported it into eclipse.

When I am trying to run the `main()` method in `org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticSearch` class (which is the entry point for starting elasticsearch) getting the following error:

`ERROR: the system property [es.path.conf] must be set`

I tried setting the system variable `ES_PATH_CONF` to 
`E:\Elasticsearch\Github\elasticsearch-master\distribution\src\main\resources\config`.

But it’s not working I am still getting the same error.  Is the above location to `ES_PATH_CONF` variable correct? Is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The location of the config directory can be set with following **VM** Option:

```
-Des.path.conf=/path/to/config/
```

Also, in your situation, it might be necessary to set the Elasticsearch **path.home** variable:

```
-Des.path.home=/path/to/elasticsearch/home/dir
```